# How to compare two dates without the use of objects?

Tags: java, compareto

/** Reports whether or not date1 comes earlier in time than date2. For     example, isEarlierThan("12-01-2015",
"02-15-2017") is true but isEarlierThan("10-11-2016", "10-11-2016") and isEarlierThan("09-09-1967", "02-15-1933")is false.
* /

```
public static boolean isEarlierThan (String date1, String date2) 

{
    if(date1.compareTo(date2) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (date1.compareTo(date2) <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This code works sometimes but no always. I have ran a tests case and it fails. The following test case is below.

```
public void testIsEarlierThan () 
{
    assertTrue(isEarlierThan("12-01-2015", "02-15-2017"));
    assertFalse(isEarlierThan("10-11-2016", "10-11-2016"));
    assertFalse(isEarlierThan("09-09-1967", "02-15-1933"));
    assertTrue(isEarlierThan("02-14-2017", "02-15-2017"));
}
```

When I run the test case, only the first two work then it stops at the third one. But I don't understand whats wrong? if the first one works shouldn't the third one work just fine? Thanks in advance!

Comment: because this is how string comparison works, `9` is after `2` for 3rd example

Comment: Why? when `Date.compareTo()` already works? and this doesn't? Can't? What is your aversion to using objects?

Comment: Oh.... but twelve is after 02 isn't it?

Comment: Of course, but that gives the wrong answer, because 2015 is before 2017.

Comment: @EJP my aversion to it is that my teacher won't let us. He insists that we find another to do it but I don't know another way except string comparison which also doesn't work.

Comment: You have to isolate the year, the month, and the day, and compare them in that order.

Comment: Are you allowed to use code?

Comment: Ok. that helps. so basically substring then compare then concat?

Comment: haha @shmosel we sure are, but only what he tell us.

Comment: anyway thanks Guys. definitely helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. And for future reference if anyone has a similar question.

```
public static boolean isEarlierThan (String date1, String date2)
{

    String month1 = date1.substring(0, 2);
    String month2 = date2.substring(0, 2);

    String day1 = date1.substring(3, 5);
    String day2 = date2.substring(3, 5);

    String year1 = date1.substring(6, 10);
    String year2 = date2.substring(6, 10);

    date1 = year1 + month1 + day1; // + month1 + day1
    date2 = year2 + month2 + day2; // + month2 + day2

    if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically I have a method that takes the two dates, takes them apart into a year, a month, and a day. Then puts them back together in a different order so that when I compare them it will print the which true if date1 is before date2 or false if date1 is after or equal to date2.